# Painting the same rectangle twice will look different

Tags: android, android-graphics

I have a custom view and I realized that some lines look darker than others. After some investigation I found that it is not a feeling but reality. The code that paints them is the same but it is called multiple times. If it is called once the line is light gray. If I call it again the line will be dark gray. Why? (nexus 4 with Android 5.1)

```
bgPaint = new Paint();
bgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
bgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
bgPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);

borderPaint = new Paint();
borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
borderPaint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);

canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(tile.getX() + 1, tile.getY() + 1, tile.getXx() - 1, tile.getYy() - 1),
        roundRadius, roundRadius, borderPaint);
canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(tile.getX() + 1, tile.getY() + 1, tile.getXx() - 1, tile.getYy() - 1),
        roundRadius, roundRadius, bgPaint);
```

Here it is an example. The bottom right tile is darker.

[image: example]

Update: the first `drawRoundRect` is responsible. I commented out the second one and I can reproduce this behaviour without it. But to be honest - the second call will render it correctly - dark gray. But why the first call renders it lighter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `.setAntiAlias(true);` the edge of the shape is blended with the colour(s) which are already there.

So rather than blending `DKGRAY` with white as with the first pass, it's blending `DKGRAY` with `DKGRAY` and giving a darker appearance.

Comment: Thank you, good catch. If I turn it off this behaviour is gone. On the other hand it looks ugly without antialiasing. How can I have both - nice look and same look regardless of number of calls? I try to implement highlighting - when user selects a tile, I change background color. When he selects another tile I want to paint it as it used to be.

Comment: You could repaint the whole scene when there is a change, each tile being painted just once with either the highlighted colour or not.

Comment: I can give a try and measure the timing. I may be overoptimizing the code. I thought of another solution - to remember the tile in memory (Bitmap??) and paint it black, oops back :-)

Comment: Many games redraw the whole screen 60 times a second, this is just redrawing when the user changes the selected tile.

Comment: FYI: redrawing complete set of tiles takes 12 ms, rendering affected tile take 1 ms. This is acceptable. But when I redraw the screen second time all lines change color now.

Comment: "But when I redraw the screen second time all lines change color now" You must start by clearing the canvas to white.